# SwipeCellKit deleting last row in tableView create an error

Tags: swift, uitableview

deleting a row in tableView is working fine until it's a last existing row.
Then i get crash: 
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)."

I understand that there's different number of cells than what is expected and its in this function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if categoryArray?.count == 0 {  // <<-- i imagine this line cause problem, though deleting it will not let me show "no categories made yet" and while it would be better to use "if let" statement i make "array" in realm which never is nil as its being created with 0 elements(which is not nil) 
        return 1
    }

    return categoryArray?.count ?? 1
}
```

the question is how can i implement this in way that deleting would work and still i could show kind a "replacement" cell that would show instead of empty tableView.

here's whole swipe to delete function:

extension CategoriesViewController: SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
    guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

    let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in

        do{
            try self.realm.write{
                self.realm.delete((self.categoryArray?[indexPath.row])!)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error deleting category\(error)")
        }
    }

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your issue is tied to how you're updating the data source. First and foremost, I recommend against artificially showing 1 cell when you have 0.  There are other ways to show an empty table view (add a view dynamically to display that the table is empty).  That being said, I would change your code in the tableView func you have displayed.

Secondly, I can't tell without seeing the rest of your code, but it looks like you are removing the data from the source, but do you ever refresh the local array that backs your table view? If you don't you will get the error you have above.  So how to fix it, right?

The key here is to ensure that you update both the data backing your model as well as the local model that is driving your table view.

**EDIT**
Regarding the question of how to display an empty tableview, try the following:

```
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let numOfSectons: Int = 1;
    if (itemStore.allItems.count>0){
        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        tableView.backgroundView = nil
    } else{
        let noDataFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height)
        let noData: UILabel = UILabel(frame: noDataFrame)
        noData.text = "No Items!"
        noData.textColor = .black
        noData.textAlignment = .center
        tableView.backgroundView = noData
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }
    return numOfSectons
}
```

In the above example, my model backing the tableView is "itemStore." This will automatically display when there are no items, regardless of if the model loads empty, or if you delete items from the model.

Comment: I'm sorry for delay but had no chance to get into this one back in last week, any tips how i can show empty table view other way(i mean i need to show somth instead of empty table view or at least i would like to) 
and for error its not about data being updated i use realm and its fine i just create artificial cell thats whats problem coz i do not show anything program is going fine i just want to tell user that he got no categories created yet.

Comment: I edited the response to hopefully answer your follow-on. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much it's work for me and save my imported time. @JohnAyers

Comment: @Digvijay, glad to help! Make sure you check out SwiftUI when iOS 13 is released, a lot of this becomes unnecessary.

Comment: I know @JohnAyers SwiftUI in many functions are inbuilt provide this lib.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete last row in TableView and reload your tableView after realm block.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
guard orientation == .right else { return nil }

let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { 
action, indexPath in

    do{
        try self.realm.write{
            self.realm.delete((self.categoryArray?[indexPath.row])!)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error deleting category\(error)")
    }
   yourTableView.deleteRows(at: indexPath.row)
   yourTableView.reloadData()
    }

    return [deleteAction]
   }
```